# What is an aggregation hierarchical rollup?

Tags: elasticsearch, analytics

I have just recently started training for elasticsearch technology and in their book they mentioned this:

> Aggregations allow hierarchical rollups too. For example, let’s find the average age of employees who share a particular interest:

Please find the link to the book, and the context of this quote by following the [analytics section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_analytics.html).

So my question is: What exactly is a hierarchical rollup?

I have consulted [an article in searchbusinessanalytics](http://searchbusinessanalytics.techtarget.com/feature/What-is-a-data-rollup) but I don't understand what is the relationship between the explanation they gave and the meaning of the word as quoted above. So if someone could clarify the relationship between the two if it exists.

N.B: Here is a quote from the previously mentionsed article in searchbusinessanalytics:

> The simplest definition of data rollup is that we convert categories to variables.

Thanks.